# C++ library for rotating a point over a given axis?

Tags: c++, geometry, graph, point

Does anyone know of a graphing library for simple transformation of a point from one coordinate system to another coordinate system which is rotated by a angle and some point transformation and just for 2d?
And any graphing tool for plotting and verifying the same visually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

double[3][3]

Comment: actually I like this answer. Why link to some library when all that is needed is one matrix multiplication.

Comment: I don't like that answer. It could have been a little bit more verbose than this. In essence you are right, and my answer is also one pointing to a library that contains simple classes to do this sort of affine transformations, but simply stating "double[3][3]" is a bit cryptic, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

[GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) includes pretty much every graphic transform you could ask for, and while it is big and hence takes some time to get used to, it is a great framework to move forward with.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a library, but it's a blog by someone who does this kind of thing:

http://polymathprogrammer.com/

It's got some good theory if you want to know the "behind the scenes".

Answer (score 0):

The [Angtigrain Geometry](http://www.antigrain.com/) library contains code that can do this, and you can also go farther and use it for drawing as well, but you don't have to. You should look at the agg::trans_affine class in the agg_trans_affine.h file.

Dave